# Fuse camel context hawtio not refreshing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jbossfuse, hawtio

Probably a Chrome issue, more than a Fuse issue, but not sure:

I have Fuse 7.3 installed, and if I load hawtio in Chrome, it's not showing my newly deployed route.

If I open in Incognito mode or in Firefox, I can see it.

I've tried CRTL-R, CTRL-F5, and nothing.  Logging out, logging in, nope.
Any idea?

Comment: That is weird. What happens if you do "hard reload" CTRL-SHIFT-R?

Comment: Nope.  It's pretty weird.  Service is installed, camel routes are being used.  Shows up in FF or incognito mode, won't show up in Chrome. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯